# How do I reduce the size of inference rule?

Tags: fonts, floats, packages

I am using package `mathpartir`, with environment `mathpar`. In the environment I am using command `\inferrule` to write down some inference rules. The problem is that this rules are just too big, and I have way too many in my document so I'm struggling to fit them. I tried some ideas to try to lower the font size but it didn't work. I am also not sure if just trying to scale the graph is a good idea because I want the rules themselves to be smaller, so that they fit better in the figure.

Minimal example of what my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{mathpar}
    \inferrule*[left=Rule-X] { x = 1 }
      { x = 10 }
    \inferrule*[left=Rule-Y] { y = 1 }
      { y = 10 }
  \end{mathpar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: As always on this site: please provide a full but minimal example. Then it is a lot easier to test your code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, done.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why just reducing the font size does not work and what you would like to do? It is of course a bad idea, to reduce the font size too much as it will make your document hard to read, but `\small` is probably fine. If reducing the font size does not do the job, in what way do you imagine making this smaller? If possible, try to make a picture showing what you are looking for.

Comment: Where would you put the `\small`? I tried to do something like this I couldn't get it to scale down the font.

Comment: Just writing `\begin{mathpar}\tiny ...` will giver smaller results.   Section 3.6 of the documentation tells you to adjust the label style too. But is this what you want?

Comment: Oh great! This is what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set globally a style for the labels:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\makeatletter
\define@key {mprset}{style}[1]{\def\TirNameStyle{#1}}
\makeatother

\mprset{style={\scriptsize\scshape}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mathpar}
  \inferrule*[left=Rule-X] { x = 1 }
    { x = 10 }
  \inferrule*[left=Rule-Y] { y = 1 }
    { y = 10 }
\end{mathpar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `leftstyle` or `rightstyle` for setting just the left labels or the right labels, respectively.

The code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is necessary because of a funny bug in the package. No change is needed for the `leftstyle` and `rightstyle` keys. In the original code we find

```
\define@key {mprset}{style}[1]{\def\TirNameStyle{#1}def}
```

which would typeset `def` when the key is set.

If your aim is to print the whole thing in reduced size:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\makeatletter
\define@key {mprset}{style}[1]{\def\TirNameStyle{#1}}
\makeatother

\AtBeginEnvironment{mathpar}{\scriptsize}
\mprset{style={\scriptsize\scshape}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mathpar}
  \inferrule*[left=Rule-X] { x = 1 }
    { x = 10 }
  \inferrule*[left=Rule-Y] { y = 1 }
    { y = 10 }
\end{mathpar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also selectively apply a size to the environment, but this requires using a different name.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}

\makeatletter
\define@key {mprset}{style}[1]{\def\TirNameStyle{#1}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{mymathpar}[1][]
 {%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{mathpar}{\scriptsize}%
  \mprset{style={#1\scshape}}%
  \mathpar
 }
 {\endmathpar}

\begin{document}

\begin{mymathpar}
  \inferrule*[left=Rule-X] { x = 1 }
    { x = 10 }
  \inferrule*[left=Rule-Y] { y = 1 }
    { y = 10 }
\end{mymathpar}

\begin{mymathpar}[\scriptsize]
  \inferrule*[left=Rule-X] { x = 1 }
    { x = 10 }
  \inferrule*[left=Rule-Y] { y = 1 }
    { y = 10 }
\end{mymathpar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

@andrew-swann, in the comments, pointed out that it is possible to just scale down the font by specifying the font size in envinroment `mathpar`, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{mathpar}\tiny
    \inferrule*[leftstyle={\tiny \sc},left=Rule-X] { x = 1 }
      { x = 10 }
    \inferrule*[leftstyle={\tiny \sc},left=Rule-Y] { y = 1 }
      { y = 10 }
  \end{mathpar}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Notice that in the labels I'm also choosing the font size and the `\sc` font style. And it is important to define the style before defining the label as it will not work in the opposite order.

Comment: Shouldn't `\tiny` be added after `\begin{mathpar}`?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I changed it.