# Is \inferrule* inside gather* not centered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath, fractions, gather

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpartir}% version 1.3.2 or 1.4.0
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \inferrule*[left=M,right=M]{premises}{conclusion}\\
  \textsc{\small M}\mskip5mu\frac{premises}{conclusion}\mskip5mu{\textsc{\small M}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields

[image: output]

As you see, the second inference rule is slightly shifted to the right with respect to the first one. So one of them is necessarily not centered, and my hunch is that `\inferrule*` of mathpartir is the culprit.  Is this really so, or is `gather*` or `\frac` at fault? Any fix or a workaround?  The maintainer of mathpartir has been informed.

Comment: For another funny bug in `mathpartir`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622102/4427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From playing around with the code, from what I can tell, this seems to be the result of a spurious space added at the end of the starred version of `\inferrule` inside the macro `\mpr@inferstar@`.

It looks like you can patch the command with the `xpatch` package as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpartir}% version 1.3.2 or 1.4.0
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\mpr@inferstar@}{\mpr@vdots$ }{\mpr@vdots$}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \inferrule*[left=M,right=M]{premises}{conclusion}\\
  \textsc{\small M}\mskip5mu\frac{premises}{conclusion}\mskip5mu{\textsc{\small M}}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image: inferstar* after patching]

Comment: It should be `\xpatchcmd{\mpr@inferstar@}{\mpr@vdots$ }{\mpr@vdots$}{}{}`

Comment: Not sure why it matters, but sure, I'll switch to that.

Comment: I guess you hit a hidden feature of `etoolbox`. For some reason, your patch also removes the space token, which it shouldn’t.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!